# Google Map Polyline screen coordinates

Tags: android

I have a simple Google Map (V2) polyline, based on 5 LanLong objects. And i need:

1) Make this clickable (which i assume can be done by implementing onClickListener interface on subclass of Polyline class)

```
ArrayList<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();

        coordinates.add(new LatLng(37.345, 56.432));
        coordinates.add(new LatLng(39.234, 50.451));
        coordinates.add(new LatLng(45.798, 24.345));
        coordinates.add(new LatLng(34.783, 70.345));
        coordinates.add(new LatLng(14.234, 23.453));

        PolylineOptions path = new PolylineOptions();
        path.addAll(coordinates);
        path.width(5);
        path.color(Color.RED);
        path.geodesic(true);
```

2) If click was on polyline - set a marker at nearest vertex of this polyline. I think i can get screen coordinates of touch event, but how can i get screen coordinates of vertex point of this polyline?

Or maybe there is simpler approach?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a sulution to my question. I post code of onMapClick() method for anyone who struggling:

```
@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng clickCoordinates) {
        for (LatLng pathCoordinates : path.getPoints()) {
            float[] results = new float[1];
            Location.distanceBetween(clickCoordinates.latitude, clickCoordinates.longitude,
                    pathCoordinates.latitude, pathCoordinates.longitude, results);

            if (results[0] < 100) {
                if (currentMarker != null) {
                    currentMarker.remove();
                }
                currentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(pathCoordinates.latitude, pathCoordinates.longitude)));
            }
        }
    }
```